# Have array of object, while clicking on add-to-bag button if item is already exist just want to update Qty count

Tags: javascript

```
let cartData = [];
const item = {
  product_name: "ProductName1",
  product_image_url: "imageURL1",
  price: "28",
  qty: 1
};
```

When clicking add to button, if I add the same item expected output would be like this:

```
cartData = [{
  product_name: "ProductName1",
  product_image_url: "imageURL1",
  price: "28",
  qty: 2
}]
```

And when clicking it again, it would be like this:

```
cartData = [{
  product_name: "ProductName1",
  product_image_url: "imageURL1",
  price: "28",
  qty: 1
}, {
  product_name: "ProductName2",
  product_image_url: "imageURL2",
  price: "38",
  qty: 1
}]
```

Comment: so did you make any attempt at solving it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a product to an array, first check if the product with the product_name is already in the array.use the 'find' function to find the element in the array by the criterion if it is there